# Problem using xng-breadcrumb 9.0.0 library, application cannot boostrapping

Tags: node.js, angular, xng-breadcrumb

I faced problem after first time installing xng-breadcrumb 9.0.0. My app after `ng serve` cannot start:
`TypeError: Cannot create property 'message' on string 'C:\Users\...\node_modules\xng-breadcrumb\fesm2015\xng-breadcrumb.mjs: This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 14.0.0, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.`

Screenshot from terminal:
[image: screen_1]

It seams that I have too old version of Angular which I think isn't old: [image]

Is it problem related to compatibility of versions?
Or what can caauses this issue and hhow can I solve it?

I tried to install older version of xng-breadcrumb but same result.

I can add that I have just updated Angular and Node.js today if it's matter.

Thanks for help for newbie.

**Edit:**

I suppose that now everything is updated:[image]

But after that I faced other problem  (I don't know if screenshots are more acceptable rather than of piece of code):
[image]

The first issue I fixed this way:

```css
// @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

But stays the second problem with: `Property 'get' in type 'ToastInjector' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Injector'.`

Comment: The xng-breadcrumb 9.0 requires angular 15. Your angular is 13 (although the CLI is 15)

Comment: @Jimmy Do I need to update `@angular-devkit/build-angular` and `@angular-devkit/core` apart by single commannd (`npm install @angular-devkit/core` and `ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular`)?

Comment: @Jimmy I have just updated my post.

Comment: You can see it's from ngx-toast, which is completely different from your original question. You should close this one and create a new one, but I urge you to do your research before creating a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update `@angular-devkit/build-angular` and `@angular-devkit/core` by using commannds:

- `npm install @angular-devkit/core`
- `ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular`